# ASP.NET Core WebAPI Latest And Best approach in 2019 to do geocoding and Reverse geocoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, geospatial, geocoding

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.2.3 with MySql, ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebApi

Yes, I know this question(Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding) has been asked hundred times, but they are out of date. In the year of 2019, I would like to find out the latest and best approach of calculating geolocations.

In my project, I have addresses in Property table and I need to

1. convert address to lat and lng
2. calculate distance between 2 addresses
3. better not depend on 3rd party Lib e.g. Google Map API

I know we can use EF Core to do the geocoding and probably calculate distance, but I found a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/ef/core/modeling/spatial) saying it's only for SqlServer, InMemory, PostgreSql etc. MySql is not on the list.

Then I found [System.Spatial](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Spatial/), however it targets for the old .Net Framework.
Then [Microsoft.Spatial](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Spatial/)(it targets .NET Platform Standard 1.1, so I guess it should be okay for .Net Core 2.2, correct?), but when I opened the [git sample](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/tree/master/test/FunctionalTests/Microsoft.Spatial.Tests), it is about 2 years old.

I really appreciate if anyone could point me the right direction.

Thank you.

**Update**

After reading through the [OData Spatial Data](https://odata.github.io/odata.net/#03-01-define-spatial-property), I found it's tightly bound to MS SQL and has certain limitations (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/using-geospatial-data/)? However I am using MySql and seems this is not the approach I could use. Also this article was written back in 2011 and cannot see recent update.

**Update 2**
I have found a [NuGet Package](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi)
**Just wonder whether this can be used in .Net Core 2.2?**

On it's github it says for .NET Core, BUT when I try to install it from the NuGet Package Manager, I saw it has dependency on .NetFramework v4.5. 
[image]

As .NetFramework isn't cross platform  ,does it mean this NuGet Package won't be running properly on Linux ?

Comment: How do you plan to convert an address to a lat and long without a 3rd party lib?  You either need a library or database with addresses and lat/long.

Comment: hi @jdweng if you take a took the Microsoft.Spatial link I provided in the question, you probably would find the answer.

Comment: I'm not going through the source code to find where the address are coming from.  I asked you to provide the answer since you do not want to use Google Map API. What is the connection string where the addresses are coming from that contains "BOTH" the address and the lat/long?

Comment: The addresses, let's say 2, come from database, then I need to find out how to geocode them into 2 pairs of lat and lng. Then find a way to calculate the distance. Microsoft.Spatial provides this function, but not sure whether it is the latest and best approach, hence I'm asking this question here.

Comment: First determine if you really have a database with Address and lat/long.  The Google API is a very large database that contains the address and lat/long.  Microsoft Spatial does not get the database from thin air.  Once you have a database then you need to create a query that returns the lat/long from an address.  You first need a lat/long before you calculate distance.  The distance is the easy part.  The hard part is getting the lat/long.

Comment: There is no "best" approach to this. It depends on your application, its capabilities, and what services, if any, you choose to utilize. You need to do your own research.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Hi there, I have done my research and am still feeling confused, if the best approach is not suitable, then how about the latest approach?

Comment: There is no "latest" approach. You're seeking some sort of best practice here, and it doesn't exist. You need to find a solution that meets your needs and then implement it. If you run into issues during the implementation, *then* you can ask specific questions about that. Otherwise, we can't help you. If you're confused, then you need to do still more research, take a class, read a book, find a video, or other training etc. That's all on you.

Answer (score 1):

The spatial data types are merely there to calculate distances between lat/lon pairs, and to calculate whether a certain lat/lon lies within a certain radius of another lat/lon.

Addresses (being street names, house numbers, city names, zip codes and any combination thereof) get updated on a daily basis as new streets and new buildings are constructed every day.

So you will need a frequently updated database that maps addresses to lat/lons. If you don't want to use a third-party API [such as Google offers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding), you'll have to download and incorporate a database that does have this data.

One of such instances is [OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data), where you can download the data and host the search API [nomatim](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Import-and-Update/). By the time you've read the how-to you'll decide you *do* want to offload this to a third party.

Comment: Make sense. I have actually found this one: https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi  Just wonder whether this can be used in .Net Core 2.2? On it's github it says for .NET Core, but when I try to install it from the NuGet Package Manager, I saw it has dependency on .NetFramework v4.5. As .NetFramework isn't cross platform  ,does it mean this NuGet Package won't be running properly on Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I use Google Api to do the geocoding with a RestSharp to make the api call.

Google Api does have NuGet Package, but it doesn't contain the Geocoding API as discussed [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1375)